# Table with conditions and parameters ? Where?

Tags: linux, unix, scripting

I'm wondering is there a table which includes all of the parameters for scripting: -n, -z  ? For example:

```
if [ **-z** $1 ]
elif [ **-n** $1 ]
```

and all of the others?

Comment: `man bash` Look for "CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS". If you're using `zsh` or `ksh` or something other than `bash`, look that the man page for that shell instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Or this: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html

What other parameters do you want to know about? Along similar lines, bash internal variables - http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

You can find most (all?) of this in `man bash`.